# Minimax algorithm for ConnectX not working as expected

Tags: python, kaggle, minimax, game-ai

I am currently following the Introduction to Game AI course on Kaggle Learn. This is my code for the exercise N-step Lookahead, but I could not get it to work. My agent cannot even do simple moves like blocking the opponent (random agent) from winning.
Here's the code to my agent:

```py
def my_agent(obs, config):
    
    ###########
    # Imports #
    ###########
    import random
    import numpy as np
    
    ####################
    # Helper functions #
    ####################
    # Gets board at next step if agent drops piece in selected column
    def drop_piece(grid, col, mark, config):
        next_grid = grid.copy()
        for row in range(config.rows-1, -1 ,-1):
            if next_grid[row][col] == 0:
                break
        next_grid[row][col] == mark
        return next_grid
                
    # Helper function for get_heuristic: check if window meets heuristic conditions
    def check_window(window, num_discs, piece, config):
        return (window.count(piece) == num_discs and window.count(0) == config.inarow-num_discs)
    
    # Helper function for get_heuristic: counts number of windows satisfying specified heuristic conditions
    def count_windows(grid, num_discs, piece, config):
        num_windows = 0
        # horizontal
        for row in range(config.rows):
            for col in range(config.columns-(config.inarow-1)):
                window = list(grid[row, col:col+config.inarow])
                if check_window(window, num_discs, piece, config):
                    num_windows += 1
        # vertical
        for row in range(config.rows-(config.inarow-1)):
            for col in range(config.columns):
                window = list(grid[row:row+config.inarow, col])
                if check_window(window, num_discs, piece, config):
                    num_windows += 1
        # positive diagonal (upper left part of board, extend right and downwards)
        for row in range(config.rows-(config.inarow-1)):
            for col in range(config.columns-(config.inarow-1)):
                window = list(grid[range(row, row+config.inarow), range(col, col+config.inarow)])
                if check_window(window, num_discs, piece, config):
                    num_windows += 1
        # negative diagonal (lower left part of board, entend right and upwards)
        for row in range(config.inarow-1, config.rows):
            for col in range(config.columns-(config.inarow-1)):
                window = list(grid[range(row, row-config.inarow, -1), range(col, col+config.inarow)])
                if check_window(window, num_discs, piece, config):
                    num_windows += 1
        return num_windows
    
    # Helper function for minimax: calculate heuristic for grid
    def get_heuristic(grid, mark, config):
        num_threes = count_windows(grid, 3, mark, config)
        num_fours = count_windows(grid, 4, mark, config)
        num_threes_opp = count_windows(grid, 3, mark%2+1, config)
        num_fours_opp = count_windows(grid, 4, mark%2+1, config)
        score = 1*num_threes + 1e5*num_fours - 100*num_threes_opp - 1000*num_fours_opp
        return score
    
    # Uses minimax to calculate value of dropping piece in selected column
    def score_move(grid, col, mark, config, nsteps):
        next_grid = drop_piece(grid, col, mark, config)
        score = minimax(next_grid, nsteps-1, False, mark, config)
        return score
    
    # Helper function for minimax: Check if agent or opponent has 4 in a row in the window
    def is_terminal_window(window, config):
        return window.count(1) == config.inarow or window.count(2) == config.inarow
    
    # Helper function for minimax: Check if game has ended
    def is_terminal_node(grid, config):
        # Check for draw 
        if list(grid[0, :]).count(0) == 0:
            return True
        # Check for win: horizontal, vertical, or diagonal
        # horizontal 
        for row in range(config.rows):
            for col in range(config.columns-(config.inarow-1)):
                window = list(grid[row, col:col+config.inarow])
                if is_terminal_window(window, config):
                    return True
        # vertical
        for row in range(config.rows-(config.inarow-1)):
            for col in range(config.columns):
                window = list(grid[row:row+config.inarow, col])
                if is_terminal_window(window, config):
                    return True
        # positive diagonal
        for row in range(config.rows-(config.inarow-1)):
            for col in range(config.columns-(config.inarow-1)):
                window = list(grid[range(row, row+config.inarow), range(col, col+config.inarow)])
                if is_terminal_window(window, config):
                    return True
        # negative diagonal
        for row in range(config.inarow-1, config.rows):
            for col in range(config.columns-(config.inarow-1)):
                window = list(grid[range(row, row-config.inarow, -1), range(col, col+config.inarow)])
                if is_terminal_window(window, config):
                    return True
        return False

    def minimax(node, depth, maximizingPlayer, mark, config):
        is_terminal = is_terminal_node(node, config)
        valid_moves = [c for c in range(config.columns) if node[0][c] == 0]
        if depth == 0 or is_terminal:
            return get_heuristic(node, mark, config)
        if maximizingPlayer:
            value = -np.Inf
            for col in valid_moves:
                child = drop_piece(node, col, mark, config)
                value = max(value, minimax(child, depth-1, False, mark, config))
            return value
        else:
            value = np.Inf
            for col in valid_moves:
                child = drop_piece(node, col, mark%2+1, config)
                value = min(value, minimax(child, depth-1, True, mark, config))
            return value

    #########################
    # Agent makes selection #
    #########################
    N_STEPS = 3
    valid_moves = [col for col in range(config.columns) if obs.board[col] == 0]
    grid = np.asarray(obs.board).reshape(config.rows, config.columns)
    scores = dict(zip(valid_moves, [score_move(grid, col, obs.mark, config, N_STEPS) for col in valid_moves]))
    print(scores)
    max_cols = [key for key in scores.keys() if scores[key] == max(scores.values())]
    return random.choice(max_cols)
```

And here's the output from printing the scores(key is column number, value is the score for each move):

```
{0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0}
{0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0}
{0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0}
{0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0}
{0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0}
{0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0}
{0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0}
{0: -99.0, 1: -99.0, 2: -99.0, 3: -99.0, 4: -99.0, 5: -99.0, 6: -99.0}
{0: -99.0, 1: -99.0, 2: -99.0, 3: -99.0, 4: -99.0, 5: -99.0, 6: -99.0}
{0: -99.0, 1: -99.0, 2: -99.0, 3: -99.0, 4: -99.0, 5: -99.0, 6: -99.0}
{0: -99.0, 1: -99.0, 2: -99.0, 3: -99.0, 4: -99.0, 5: -99.0}
{0: -99.0, 1: -99.0, 2: -99.0, 3: -99.0, 4: -99.0, 5: -99.0}
```

I believe I made a stupid mistake here, but I just can't seem to find it. Can anyone help me?

Btw I am a newbie in StackOverflow so please point out if there's any problem with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hour, I figured out my mistake. It was a very silly one.
In the `drop_piece` function, the correct line should be

```
next_grid[row][col] = mark
```

But I wrote:

```
next_grid[row][col] == mark
```

Everything is working fine now.